# If $(x^2 - x - 1)^n = a_{2n}x^{2n} + a_{2n - 1}x^{2n - 1} + \cdots + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$, then find the value of $a_0 + a_2 + a_4 + \cdots + a_{2n}$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, problem-solving, factoring

So here is the Problem :-

> If $(x^2 - x - 1)^n = a_{2n}x^{2n} + a_{2n - 1}x^{2n - 1} + \cdots + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$, then find the value of $a_0 + a_2 + a_4 + \cdots + a_{2n}$ .

I don't know how to factorise $(x^2 - x - 1)^n$ and I was only able to solve this by substituting $n = 1$, where that would give $$(x² - x - 1) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0.$$

This immediately gives the answer as $0$ . But I want a solution for $n$ itself, but not substituting $n$ as any number. Can anyone give me an idea of it ?

Comment: Plug in $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Can you combine these results to obtain the desired sum?

Comment: Doing that we get :- $$(-1)^n = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{2n}$$$$ 1 = a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - ... + a_{2n}$$

Comment: @Anonymous Now add them together. What happens?

Comment: Then we get $1 + (-1)^n = 2(a_0 + a_2 + a_4 + ... + a_{2n})$

Comment: @Anonymous Do you see how this solves the problem?

Comment: @YiFan I got it , then we get $(a_0 + a_2 + a_4 + ... + a_{2n}) = \frac{(1 + (-1)^n)}{2}$

Comment: @Anonymous Yup, that's right! So when $n$ is even the answer is $1$, and when $n$ is odd, it is $0$.

Comment: Okay yeah! Thank you for the hint @YiFan .

Comment: No problem. Maybe you should thank @SameerKailasa too :)

Comment: Ok so I am voting to close this question as a duplicate so that others don't have to see it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $x=1$ into the equality we have
$(-1)^n=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots+a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}$,
Substituting $x=-1$ into the equality we have
$1=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\ldots-a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}$,

Adding these two, we get
$2(a_0+a_2+\ldots+a_{2n-2}+a_{2n})=(-1)^n+1$

Therefore,
$a_0+a_2+\ldots+a_{2n-2}+a_{2n}=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2} =\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases} $